# Remove blue dots on anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have a few anchors in my `body`:

```
<a href="link1.html"></a>
<a href="link2.html"></a>
<a href="link3.html"><img src="img1.png" /></a>
```

The ones with an image in it have a weird blue dot on the bottom-right handed side.

I tried `a { border: none; }` for css but they are still there!

Any help much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Your link is dead btw

Comment: Your image doesn't work. Try [imgur](http://imgur.com/).

Comment: your Click Me is broken

Comment: `a {text-decoration: none; }` did it! thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

css:

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

this should work, it worked with me.

Comment: worked dear C Travel! thanks a lot... next time i try directly a reset.css!

Comment: no problem! had the same problem, and i was happy to when i found it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your anchor tag is underlining which it does by default. 
Try setting the `text-decoration` of the anchors to `none`.

This should fix it:

```
a{ text-decoration: none; }
```